# Stored procedure - Operand type clash: smallint is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a dropdownlist of users and `value (userD)` but have issues getting the `UserID` value returned in json, instead of real `user id value`

I get
`<option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Test User1</option>
<option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Test User2</option>`

followed by the 
*Operand type clash: smallint is incompatible with uniqueidentifier* **error** in my console

**Here is my stored procedure**

```
 USE [DojoDB]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROC [dbo].[rpGetUsers]  
    AS
        BEGIN  
    SELECT [UserID] AS ID,
          [UserFirstname] ,[UserSurname] 

      FROM [DojoDB].[dbo].[System_User]

         END
```

**Here is my class**

```
public class rpusers
    {
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserFirstname { get; set; }
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
        public string FullName {

            get { return UserFirstname + " " + UserSurname; }

        }
        public int InstanceID { get; set; }
        public int IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public List<rpusers> rpusersList { get; set; }
        public List<rpusersRecord> rpusersRecordList { get; set; }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FullName, new SelectList(Model.rpusersList, "UserID", "FullName"), new
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult rpusersChart()
    {
        rpusers objrpusers = new rpusers();
        rpusersAction objRusersAction = new rpusersAction();
        try
        {
            objrpusers.rpusersList = objRusersAction.GetrpusersDetails();
            return View("~/Views/rpusers/rpusersChart.cshtml", objrpusers);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you might be trying to store a UniqueIdentifier in a short or a Guid in a SmallInt. Can you post the code?

Comment: yes sure, posting that now

Comment: @SBFrancies additionnal code added!

Comment: Thanks, what type is UserID in the database?

Comment: @SBFrancies UserID is uniqueidentifier

Comment: I've given an answer about the blank Guid. I'm not 100% sure about the error message - is InstanceID also a uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @SBFrancies Instanceid is an int, i'm currently testing your suggestion, thank you for being helpful!!

Comment: The error message suggests that somewhere you are providing a smallint value (short in C#) to the database where it is expecting a uniqueidentifier (or maybe the otherway around). It's a database error so we'd probably have to see the content of your data access layer to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Guid is blank because your stored procedure does not match the model the property is caled "ID" in the stored procedure:

```
SELECT [UserID] AS ID,
```

and "UserID" in the model:

```
public Guid UserID
```

Because the procedure returns no "UserID" column UserID is coming out as the default Guid value (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`).